# AFNetworking post data not accepted by server

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, afnetworking

I'm trying to post an encrypted json string to a server, but no matter how I use AFNetworking the server will not accept the post data.

I have this working with Postman:

[image]
AFNetworking code that I'm trying to use:

```
var encrypted: String = "70RFFwboFukuO068d2trNRgv............"

let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager(baseURL: NSURL(string: baseUrl))

manager.requestSerializer = AFHTTPRequestSerializer()
manager.requestSerializer.setValue("application/aesjson-server; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
manager.requestSerializer.setValue("gzip_aes", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept-Encoding")

manager.POST(postUrl, parameters: encrypted, success:
    { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,responseObject: AnyObject!) in
        println("Success")
    },
    failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,error: NSError!) in
        println("Failed \(error.description)")
})
```

The encrypted string is base64 encoded, as far as I can tell the server is having problems decoding it when it arrives.

**Edit:**

Thanks to Zaph's comment it looks as though AFNetworking is adding (null)= to the beginning of the post data, and url encoding the base64 string.

Post data of:

```
L9u7AvNdtJFLA7VaNR1115idL2h4tjnJ/Ij9Me+4m7svmi6x7E8RBVvNqEcNFx9YEP5595ntvfl5/05YvfztOVpBD08Ftk6AI59Sbskss+/bvW9Tnwi5h1d9e07DVSqkm6TaTl/jwnrTv/HCgI4eTIqJXcwlTz6TqUUkLvgTPj1fZKB1Fus9s4OleJVR+gX+
```

becomes:

```
(null)=L9u7AvNdtJFLA7VaNR1115idL2h4tjnJ%2FIj9Me%2B4m7svmi6x7E8RBVvNqEcNFx9YEP5595ntvfl5%2F05YvfztOVpBD08Ftk6AI59Sbskss%2B%2FbvW9Tnwi5h1d9e07DVSqkm6TaTl%2FjwnrTv%2FHCgI4eTIqJXcwlTz6TqUUkLvgTPj1fZKB1Fus9s4OleJVR%2BgX%2B
```

Is there a way to stop AFNetworking doing this?

Comment: I always just run Charles Proxy to see exactly what is being sent/received.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Zaph. I used Charles and AFNetworking seems to be adding (null)= to the beginning of the post data, and url encoding the base64 string

Comment: What does the server expect? Form formatted data or just the data? My bet with a content type of "application/aesjson-server" it just wants the data. There is an AFNetworking option to set that.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is absolute logical.

Post Data should be an NSDictionary with the key/value pairs specified.
You are posting a string and not a dictionary, so the key is set as nil.

```
let postData:NSDictionary = ["postKey": encrypted];
```

......

```
manager.POST(postUrl, parameters: postData, success:
    { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,responseObject: AnyObject!) in
        println("Success")
    },
    failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,error: NSError!) in
        println("Failed \(error.description)")
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but that was the first thing I tried. It does not work, also does not work with Postman's key:value option

Comment: Define it does not work. Attach screenshot from Charles. I'm using this (although not with Swift) on our projects and it does work fine.

Comment: I could post a screenshot, but all it would show is a 500: internal server error response from the server, and a post data of "data=my url encoded base64 string". The api wont accept key=data, and wont accept the encrypted data after it's been url encoded. Both of which AFNetworking does by default. I've found a way to make it work for this specific scenario, i'll post what worked

Comment: POST data can also be just that: data bytes. The format depends on what the server expects.

Comment: @Zaph This is what I see in the `AFHTTPRequestSerializer` class for postdata serialization `typedef NSString * (^AFQueryStringSerializationBlock)(NSURLRequest *request, NSDictionary *parameters, NSError *__autoreleasing *error);`

Comment: It is in there somewhere. AFNetworking is great but I use the Apple networking directly so I can't help with AFNetworking.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for my specific scenario. I needed to override the query sting serialisation block so AFNetworking didn't add a key, and url encode the post data:

```
  manager.requestSerializer.setQueryStringSerializationWithBlock { (request: NSURLRequest!, dict: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, error: NSErrorPointer) -> String! in
        var postString = ""
        for (key, object) in dict {
            postString += object as String
        }
        return postString
    }
```